# find cubic root of a number from 0 to 125

Tags: c, precision, cubic

I am trying to write a C code of a function that takes an integer from `0` to `125` and return the cubic root of that integer only if it's a whole number ( 1,2,3,4,5 ) and if it's not, return `0` instead. So I wrote this code:

```
unsigned int cubic(unsigned int n) {
    if (n > 125)
        return 0;
    double root = pow(n, (1 / 3.));
    double rem = (double)(roundf(root)) - root;
    if (rem != 0)
        return 0;
    else
       return roundf(root);
}
```

this function works fine with all cases except for the number `64` and `125`.
in these cases it returns `0` instead of the cubic roots of these numbers which are `4` and `5` respectively.
Can anybody explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: If the input `n` is guaranteed to be between `0` and `125`, then you may simply compare `n` against the cubes of `1` to `5`.

Comment: `pow( n, (1/3.) )` doesn't give the exact result of cube root, just print the result with more precision and you'll see. [`cbrt(n)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/cbrt) may be better but won't guarantee the correct result either, due to the nature of floating-point operations. The only way is to round the result to int and check

Comment: If you print some values, for `64` you get `root = 3.99999999999999955591 rem = 0.00000000000000044409`. Please see [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)
and [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate) It's not so much that cube root of 64 can't be accurately represented by binary floating point, but `1/3.` cannot be.

Answer (score 5):

Because `1 / 3.` cannot accurately represented as a floating point number, the floating point calculation `pow(64, (1 / 3.))` might produce a number very close to `4`, but a tiny bit smaller or larger, different enough from `4` for `(double)(roundf(root)) - root` to be different from `0`.

You could work around this precision issue this way:

```
unsigned int cubic(unsigned int n) {
    int root = (int)round(pow(n, 1 / 3.));
    if (root * root * root == n)
        return root;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Instead of `pow(n, 1 / 3.)`, you could use `cbrt(n)` if available on your system, but the precision issue might still be present.

For your goal, it seems much simpler to iterate over the possible integer roots and check:

```
unsigned int cubic(unsigned int n) {
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        unsigned int i3 = i * i * i;
        if (i3 == n)
            return i;
        if (i3 > n)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or even more explicit:

```
unsigned int cubic(unsigned int n) {
    switch (n) {
      case 1 * 1 * 1: return 1;
      case 2 * 2 * 2: return 2;
      case 3 * 3 * 3: return 3;
      case 4 * 4 * 4: return 4;
      case 5 * 5 * 5: return 5;
      default: return 0;
    }
}
```